# Can't connect tablet to VPN

Tags: tablet, vpn

I have two android devices, my phone and my tablet. In the country I live in some websites are blocked, which make some applications useless since they depend on internet connection. I tried in my phone downloading Kepard and the application works just fine, I can access any website. The problem is when I download the same application in my tablet (again, is android). And it doesn't work, I try many other VPN applications, Hotspot Shield, Hideman, hideninja, etc. and none of them worked.

I tried another Tablet (Android), installed Kepard and... It worked!. And I reached the conclusion that my tablet is the problem, and I would like to solve it, but don't know how.

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of Android is your device running on? Older versions don't have proper VPN support.

Comment: The phone (It works): 2.3

The Tablet (Doesn't work): 4.2.2

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem using psiphon and hotspot shield VPN, after rooting my device I tried using psiphin and it worked.

Comment: It would help if you technically explain how rooting the device made psiphin worked.

Comment: It used to say " socks stopped